Task Schedular Does not recognize a running instance of Outlook
I'm trying to use mSendMail() subroutine in VB Script to first check if Outlook is already running. If Outlook is running, it will proceed with sending the email using the existing instance of Outlook. Otherwise, it will start Outlook before sending the email. It works when I did it manually in Qlickview macro editor but when I tried running it from The Task Schedular it did not recognize the already running instance of outlook, it just opened another instance and could not send the email.
I am expecting the Task Schedular to recognize the running instance of outlook. here is the code:
Sub mSendMail(pdfFilePath)
Dim objOutlk 
Dim objMail 
Const olMailItem = 0

' Check if Outlook is already running
On Error Resume Next
Set objOutlk = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

' If Outlook is not running, start it
If (objOutlk = "") Then
    StartOutlook
    ' Wait for Outlook to start
    ActiveDocument.GetApplication.Sleep 5000 ' Wait for 5 seconds for Outlook to start
    ' Create a new instance of Outlook application
    Set objOutlk = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

' Create a new mail item
Set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem)

' Recipient's email address
objMail.To = "example@yahoo.com"

' Subject of the email
objMail.Subject = "Testing " & Date()

' Body of the email
objMail.HTMLBody = "Body of the email, This is an automatic generated email from QlikView."

' Add attachment (use the generated PDF file)
objMail.Attachments.Add pdfFilePath

' Send the email
objMail.Send

' Release resources
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlk = Nothing
End Sub

Sub StartOutlook()
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
oShell.Run "cmd.exe /K ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"" ", 0, False
End Sub
                  


The issue will be the security context in which the script is running, both the script execution and the Outlook instance will need to be executed in the same context for GetObject() to work as expected.
